# Linq query not working in AWS with .Net Core and EF Core

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, entity-framework-core

I am working on .NET Core 3.1 Web API with EF Core and this API is deployed to AWS Lambda. The issue am facing in below code is, it executes till the console log. Then after api returned with below message with status code

> 504 Gateway Timeout:

> "message": "Endpoint request timed out"

`CoreContext` extends `DbContext`:

```
public async Task<IList<ChannelsEnvelope>> GetChannels()
{
        using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inside scope123");  // works till here.
            var _coreContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<CoreContext>();

            var query = from a in _coreContext.DistributionChannels
                        where a.Active == true
                        orderby a.Channel ascending
                        select new ChannelsEnvelope
                        {
                            ID = a.Id,
                            Channel = a.Channel,
                            Description = a.Description
                        };

            return await query.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        }
}
```

Execution log in aws:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The method `GetRequiredService` is a part of .Net Platform Extensions. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getrequiredservice) for details.

On one hand there are certain [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/connect/net-introducing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core) on .Net Plateform Extensions and on the other hand AWS Lambda runs on Linux platform and uses a [custom runtime](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-core-3-0-on-lambda-with-aws-lambdas-custom-runtime/) which may not support all functionalities of .Net Core runtime.

Please go through the links above and confirm if the APIs used in your code are supported on AWS Lambda.

Comment: Tried using this also, but didnt work.
            using (var _coreContext = new CoreContext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("inside scope123");
                try
                {
                    var query = from a in _coreContext.DistributionChannels